# Get Datapoint Count of a Prometheus Timeseries

Tags: prometheus, victoriametrics

I have defined a recording rule for a Prometheus expression.

Rule - `rule:my_recording_rule`
Expression - `sum by(foo) (increase(some_metric{}[4w]))`

That recording rule contains data every 15 seconds. So if we take 1 minute there are 4 data points recorded.

**I want to get the total datapoint count in that recording rule.**

I tried `count(rule:my_recording_rule)` but it only gives me the number of Timeseries listed.

I want to get the data point count of each timeseries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [count_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_over_time) function. For example, the following query will return the number of raw sample during the last hour per each time series with `some_metric` name:

```
count_over_time(some_metric[1h])
```

If you need to sum datapoints across matching time series, then just wrap the query into [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum):

```
sum(count_over_time(some_metric[1h]))
```